# Verilog For loop

Tags: for-loop, verilog

I have the following code in verilog to test a For loop:

```
module test1;

reg [2:0] i;

initial
begin
    for(i=0;i<=3;i=i+1) begin
         #10;
         $display("%d",i);
    end
end

endmodule
```

The printed output shows:

0
1
2
3

Which makes sense to me. But the waveform below confuses me:

[image]

How does the reg 'i' take the value '4' here?

This is part of a bigger code I am working on where I have many nested for loops used in a testbench.

I am adding a nested loop which behaves weird:

```
module test1;

reg signed [2:0] i,j;

initial
begin
    for(i=-3;i<=3;i=i+1) begin
        for(j=-3;j<=3;j=j+1) begin
            #10;
            $display("%d   %d",i,j);
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```

The output waveform is shown below:
[image]

Why is the 2nd loop not working and first loop keep repeating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with how `for` loops know when to stop.

When you write

```
for(i=0;i<=3;i=i+1)
```

this says three things:

1. `i` starts at 0
2. The loop continues until `i<=3` becomes false
3. Each time, increment `i` by one

The thing is, `i<=3` can't become false until `i` becomes 4. When `i` becomes 4, the loop stops looping. But `i` is still 4.

---

In your nested loop example, the problem is overflow.

You have declared `j` as signed three bits:

```
reg signed [2:0] i,j;
```

But you are looping until `j` becomes 4:

```
for(j=-3;j<=3;j=j+1)
```

There is no way to represent 4 as a signed three bit integer. Because `j<=3` must always be true, the loop can never stop.